# ExecutionEngineException in Windows Phone device during navigate to a page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, exception, windows-phone-8

I have a error of class `ExecutionEngineException`. When I navigate to page:

```
 private void FriendsMainTxt_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/View/Map/UserMap.xaml?type=users", UriKind.Relative));
    }

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            if (NavigationContext.QueryString["type"] != null) //ExecutionEngineException here
            {
                typeMap = NavigationContext.QueryString["type"];
            }
       }
```

I have this error only WP8 device, in emulator I never have. After this error call

```
private void RootFrame_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                Debugger.Break();
            }
        }
```

This exception can occur during garbage collection, but how can I influence this process in a WP?

Any ideas.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't.  If you don't use any unmanaged code in your project, the kind that is likely to corrupt the GC heap, then you'll need help from Microsoft Support to chase down this bug.

Comment: I have a memory leak, my app usage more 90 mb. I use map in my project, and after I go to map, the app starts to use around 60-70 mb. And when I leave the card, memory is not freed.

Comment: ExecutionEngineException is a far bigger problem than a "memory leak".  If you hacked any code to try to reduce memory usage, and now it is crashing, then you really need to document that.

Comment: You offer to write to Microsoft Support about this?

Comment: Of course not, you'll need to do this yourself.  They will need a copy of your project to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Ok, thank! But I still want reduce memory usage, can I use protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
            System.GC.Collect();
            System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();           
        }  It's normal?

Comment: Hi @Alexandr! Is your problem solved? Now I'm facing the same issue while developing my project. However in my case the exception is thrown not only during the navigation, but mostly at random. I was not really able to find the steps to reproduce.

Comment: Hi @danyloid! Unfortunately I have not been able to solve this problem. Now I can not reproduce it. My only clue is a memory leak when using Bing maps. I think it's cause of the error. Which platform do you use?

Answer (score 1):

I also had this exception occurring at random. The problem went away after I deleted a number of breakpoints that were set with "When hit..." to produce some logging messages. Apparently, VS2012 and / or the runtime were too busy with logging to execute normally.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: I think it is a potential answer to the question. Would you like me to keep these kinds of suggestions to myself?

Comment: While this could be an answer to the question, but it is still hypothetical in nature. Such suggestions are often put in the comments. :)